# Asp mvc convert Int32 type to list<int>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, iqueryable

i have created one variable of type Int32 on my query(IQueryable) , something like this:

```
 var ExempleId = Int32.Parse(this.Table.GetCustomValueFromDictionary("exempleId").ToString());
```

And i want to call it on my view:

```
div data-rels="@Url.Action("ExempleAction", "ExempleController",new { ...,
               Model.ExempleId]       
           })">
</div>
```

This Model.ExempleId is a list of int type , because it have to accept multiple ids.

i tried to convert the ExempleId of type Int32 to list:

```
var ExempleId = new list<int>;
foreach (var value in ExempleId ) { ExempleId.add(value); }
```

but this list gave me some weird/random numbers that i don't know where it comes from.

so i would like to know how can i convert a variable of type  Int32 to list and call it on view as a list(the way it is right now).

Comment: Create with `var ExempleId = new List<int> { /*use parsed valued here*/ };` and use it in the view as `Model.ExempleId[0]`. Be sure to have a value in there or this will throw an exception.

Comment: the `Model Model.ExempleId[0]`  will only return one value so there will be no point to use a list. And if i remove the `[0 ]` position  it will give "Input string was not in a correct format.".

Comment: OK, then I don't understand what you want to do. Either `ExempleId` is `int` or `List<int>` it can't be both. Maybe some additional code would help. Please give us some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood very well (your last code quote does not make sense because you're looping through an empty list)

But here is how you could get a list of integers, from a single integer.

```
var myList = new List<int> { ExempleId };
```